# Reading through Ephesians 5 - is there any record of what Paul is quoting?

Tags: life-of-jesus, paul-apostle, resurrection, epistles

This is a quote recorded by Paul in Ephesians 5, regarding a saying about Christ. Was it something He heard when Christ came to Him or does the early Church record this quote originating elsewhere?

I've Googled the quote and came up with a commentary from [St. John of Chrysostom](https://sayingsoftheorthodoxfathers.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/awake-you-who-sleep-arise-from-the-dead-and-christ-will-give-you-light-st-john-chrysostom/). He compares them to John 3:20 (and naturally 21) and Matthew 22:32.

I'm curious if anyone knows if this is from an epistle or gospel that is not in the 66 Protestant books of the Bible?

> (Ephesians 5:14 NKJV)  Therefore He says: "Awake, you who sleep, Arise
>   from the dead, And Christ will give you light."

Comment: Paul may not, necessarily, be 'quoting'. He may be conveying, by inspiration, the breathed word of God, directly, conveyed through he (Paul) himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My copy of "The Comprehensive New Testament" (Edited by T E & J Clontz, published by Cornerstone) lists a number of cross-references for Eph 5:14.

- Isa 26:19, 51:17, 52;1, 60:1
- 4 Ezra 2:31
- Odes of Solomon 15:2
- Sibylline Oracles 1.371
- Archelaus, Disputation with Manes 43
- Clement of Alexandria, Exhortation to the Heathen 11
- Hippolytus, Refutation of all Heresies Book V.2; Treatise on Christ and Antichrist 65
- Nag Hammadi - Gospel of Truth 33

Note that these do not mean that all these are sources for Eph 5:14, far from it.  The OT references are probably the sources.  It simply means that all these references have similar wording or ideas.  This means that some of the later references could be quoting or alluding to Ephesians; or, they could both be quoting from a common (now lost) sources.  We cannot be sure.

Comment: I would agree - it looks like it is a reference to Isaiah more than the others you listed.